# Create Apklib for building with maven

Tags: java, android, maven, maven-plugin

I have Android `project A` which refers Android library `project B`, Building Project A on eclipse works fine. But my app using some system API so I thought to build using maven. I am not getting how to include Project B in Project A on maven.

(basically proj B has both source and resource)

Basically I generated B.jar and edited pom file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.me.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>myId</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <type>lib</type>
</dependency>
```

then I am able to build `A.apk` but when I launch `A.apk` application, its `crashing`. Because `project B` has some `resources` and when I generate B.jar it has only class files and don't have resources. And also I tried to generate `B.apk` and included included in maven and I couldn't able to build A.apk.

How can I solve this.

Comment: Have you tried to build B as apklib? This should generate resources for it

Comment: @Chaosit I dont know how to build apklik. I just generated B.jar but it didn't work. Can you suggest me in building apklib

Comment: you should try this in pom file for your projectB: <groupId>com.yourproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectB</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>apklib</packaging>

Comment: @Chaosit THanks for suggestion, I made it out

Answer (score 1):

First I built `B.apklib` then I included it in A project as dependency and now I am able to build `A.apk`

B.pom contains

```
    <groupId>com.mer</groupId>
    <artifactId>me</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3</version>
    <packaging>apklib</packaging>
    <name>I_am</name>
    <dependencies>
.......
        </dependencies>
```